# Python: How to access instance member from other module?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm a beginner struggling with calling an instance member from another module. My code is quite long, but I can reproduce the issue with this snippet:

mainmodule.py:

```
from othermodule import *

class Class2_in_main():
    mystring = 'Initial Value'
    print mystring

    def change_string(self, NewStringValue):
        self.mystring = NewStringValue
        print self.mystring

def main():
    MyObjectInstance = Class2_in_main()

    Object2 = othermodule.Class_in_othermodule()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

othermodule.py:

```
from mainmodule import *

class Class_in_othermodule():

    MyObjectInstance().change_string('New String Value!')
```

Here's my stack:

```
Initial Value
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mainmodule.py", line 1, in <module>
    from othermodule import *
  File "C:\PythonScripts\StackOverflowExample\othermodule.py", line 3, in <module>
    class Class_in_othermodule():
  File "C:\PythonScripts\StackOverflowExample\othermodule.py", line 6, in Class_in_othermodule
    MyObjectInstance().change_string('New String Value!')
NameError: name 'MyObjectInstance' is not defined
```

I use Python 2.7.

Any idea? I'm sorry for the bad formatting, it's my first question here, and I can't figure out how that works!

**Update**: I was able to have my code working, but I would like to understand how to call "change_string" specifically for my instance only (called MyObjectInstance), how could I do that?? Here is what I currently have:

mainmodule.py:

```
import othermodule

class Class2_in_main():
    mystring = 'Initial Value'
    print mystring

    def change_string(self, NewStringValue):
        self.mystring = NewStringValue
        print self.mystring

def main():
    global MyObjectInstance
    MyObjectInstance = Class2_in_main()

    Object2 = othermodule.Class_in_othermodule()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

othermodule.py:

```
class Class_in_othermodule():
    mainmodule.Class2_in_main().change_string('New String Value!')
```

Comment: Upvoted for a including a minimal example.

Comment: The code in `othermodule.py` doesn't make any sense. Think about it. You are defining a class and then you want to call `change_string` function from a different module. But how is that related to `Class_in_othermodule`? What exactly are you trying to achieve? BTW: circular referencing is a very bad practice IMHO.

Comment: Yes I agree that this code by itself doesn't make any sense, most probably because it's just a snippet of a very large program. But the general idea I try to achieve is to modify the attribute ("mystring") of a class instance ("MyObjectInstance") from a different module ("othermodule.py").